# Re-creating gradient effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

Tried searching for any tutorials online but I couldn't seem to find one.

How do I re-create this image color in Illustrator?

[image]

I tried using gradients but I could not seem to manipulate it to come from the middle. I also tried using mesh points, but the colors aren't as equally spaced as this.

Answer (score 5):

Which version of Adobe Illustrator are you using?
Try this and see if it works for you.

Create a rectangle with a gradient  e.g. like this:
[image]

(Remember, the first swatch in the gradient should have the same value as the last one.)

Now create a circle with a two-color radial gradient.
[image]

With the circle selected go to Object=Expand...
Select these options:
[image]
Now you should see a layer structure like below.
With a mesh and a clipping path.
Delete the clipping path.(Selected in the screenshot).
[image]

Now the circle has no clipping path, and so it should appear larger.
With your Point Selection tool, select a point related to the inner circle. Then hit delete.[image]

EDIT:
Before you continue, remember to check Distort Linear Gradient Fills inside Object= Envelope Distort= Envelope Options.

[image]

Now, select both the Circle, and the rectangle. Go to Object=Envelope Distort=Make With Top Object.
[image]
You should now have the result you where looking for. :)
[image]

If you want to edit your gradient you can switch editing area with these: [image] located in the upper-left corner of your screen:

Comment: Great solution! I love the step by step process. Now, I followed these steps and got a circle with a linear gradient across it. So I did a little investigating and found that I needed to have `Distort Linear Gradient Fills` checked inside of Object->Envelope Distort->Envelope Options. For me it was not checked, but I'm not sure which state is the default.

Comment: That is my mistake - I'm very sorry!
I, accidentally ,forgot to mention this step.
Most likely because I had mine checked already .

I hope that it didn't  make you too confused.